# LinearLayout horizontal push view off screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to put 3 views beside eachother in horizontal: TextView - SeekBar - TextView. 
Here's my illustration: 0:00 ------0------ 0:00

I want the SeekBar to flex and with two counters on each side, but the last textView dosen't show. 
Haven't really learn about this layout stuff yet in android.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/player_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Progress01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:text="@string/progress" 
        android:textColor="@color/player_duration_progress"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Duration01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:text="@string/duration"
        android:textColor="@color/player_duration_progress"/>            
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Maybe linearlayout isn't the best fit here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would use a RelativeLayout instead:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Progress01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="progress"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Duration01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Progress01"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Duration01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="duration"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thats almost perfect! The little problem is now that the seekBar float on top of the textViews, stretching all the way to the sides. Can I fix that?

Comment: hmmm ... I've doubled checked above on a real device and it works just fine: TextView - SeekBar - TextView - just the way you wanted. You sure you didn't put something in between or changed layout_toLeftOf or toRightOf? - those are the key features of the layout

Comment: I got it ... you don't want to stretch ... missread that. Will edit the response and get back

Comment: there, done! you need to put the seekbar in another ViewGroup that stretches to text views and within the ViewGroup set the witdth to "wrap_content". That should be OK

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
```

You are setting SeekBar's width to fill_parent, leaving no space to the other TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Change SeekBar LayoutWidth as wrap_content.

Check below:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```